# Symfony 5.4 debug toolbar not loading because of my dynamic route

Tags: php, symfony, routes

Im trying to create a cms with Symfony. I want users to be able to create their own pages. I got this all set up but what did not work for me was loading pages with an url that contains a `/`.

This is my route that does not allow a `/`:

```php
#[Route('/{slug}', name: 'dynamic_page', defaults: ["slug" => null], methods: ['GET'])]
public function showStoredPage(Page $page)
{
    return $this->render('blocks/base.html.twig');
}
```

If I add `requirements: ["slug" => ".+"]` to my route, I am able to go to `any/route/that/exists` with as many slashes as I wish. Which is what I want.

But after adding this I figured that my debug toolbar does not load anymore. The debug bar shows `loading...` in all pages I have. Also, when looking at the text the symfony built-in server shows in cmd, it keeps looping a request. If I wait long enough the server even crashes because it can never load the toolbar...

How can I make my toolbar load but also keep my route dynamic the way I want it? I'm using Symfony 5.4 with PHP 8+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears this can be solved very easily. I just had to add `priority: -1` to my route attribute. Now it looks like this:

```php
#[Route('/{slug}', name: 'dynamic_page', defaults: ["slug" => null], requirements: ["slug" => ".+"], methods: ['GET'], priority: -1)]
```

Also with the command `php bin/console debug:router` you can now see the route is on the bottom of the table and the toolbar will load first.

Answer (score 1):

For more control over what the route does, and does not match, without having to rely on the priority setting, you can use a more precise regex. You can use a negative lookahead to define what not to match. All the paths you want to avoid start with `'_'` so, you could use `'(?!_).+'` but that will prevent you from matching anything starting with `'_'`. To only exclude the defined routes use `'(?!_(error|wdt|profiler)).+'`

```php
#[Route('/{slug}', name: 'dynamic_page', defaults: ["slug" => null], requirements: ["slug" => "(?!_(error|wdt|profiler)).+"], methods: ['GET']]
```

Comment: Tnx, I didn't know this. Though I'd say using `priority` is a bit cleaner since it catches all routes at once.